# What is the meaning of Yang-Mills action evaluated on Levi-Civita connection?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, gauge-theory, general-relativity

On a Riemannian manifold $M$ with riemann curvature tensor $R_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$ written as (endomorphism valued) curvature two-tensor of the Levi-Civita connection  $R=R_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu\wedge dx^\nu$, consider the following term. 
 $$\int_M tr(R\wedge *R)=2\int_M tr(R_{\mu\nu}R^{\mu\nu})dvol_g=2\int_M tr(R_{\mu\nu}{}_{\rho\sigma}R^{\mu\nu\sigma\rho})dvol_g$$
This is Yang-Mills action evaluated on Levi-Civita. My questions are

What is its meaning? Is it a topological term?

Does it have any physical applications, especially in GR?

Comment: If you google "L2 norm of curvature", you'll find some papers regarding this functional, especially in dimension 4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find information about functionals that are quadratic in the curvature in Besse's book *Einstein Manifolds*.  In particular, see Chapter 4, Section H and the references cited therein.  Your questions about topological interpretations and possible connections with GR, etc., are addressed in some of those references.